# How load a javascript file dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a js file that I want to load it dynamically in a web page using JavaScript. I want to load the file after the web page has been loaded.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with pure javascript or jQuery, here is the two ways (I prefer the jQuery way):

JavaScript

```
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = 'http://url.to/your/script.js';
h.appendChild(s);
```

jQuery

```
$.getScript('http://url.to/your/script.js');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = function () {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', 'some.js');
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer you're looking for is the one that @bagonyi's already gave. I would like to add that there are also a whole lot of libraries that wrap this functionality, work cross browser and will do some optimising. I often use requireJS for this: http://requirejs.org/

Comment: While sort of a punt of an answer, I find RequireJS a very practical approach - and sure beats *another* hand-rolled implementation. However, I believe that RJS is subjects to CORS (as it uses XHR, not SCRIPT elements, IIRC).

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's not a real answer. I changed it to make clear that my answer was an addition to the correct one that was already given.